# How do you balance CSing and harassing?

Tags: league-of-legends

I always have a hard time balancing the two. When I focus on CSing I usually get harassed and when I harass I miss out a lot of CS. How do you balance the two?

Answer (score 1):

I always look at the creep waves to determine when to harass. I like to think of the situation in terms of a decision where to put each of my auto-attacks when attacking at max speed or if I want to wait on my attacks to get the response time to 0.

If the enemy creeps are all at high health (not last-hitable) and I see that one of my friendly creeps is at low health then I know that the enemy will be looking to last hit so I take that opportunity to hit them with an auto attack. Basically, if I can hit them without losing a CS or putting myself in danger then I will do so.

The main key here is to watch the creep health bars and start considering your allied creeps health in order to know when the enemy will be trying to last hit. If you know that their auto-attack will be spent on a creep then you know that you can hit them once without taking damage yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which champion. if it were caitlyn cs whenever u don't have her passive up and harass when the passive is up for extra damage. also looks for chances where u can harass and not take any damage, free hits are always good.

Answer (score 0):

If you're playing a ranged champion, keep getting CS until they're too close for comfort. Never chase them unless you're certain you can get the kill. Just deal some damage to keep them at bay so you can peacefully gain CS. If you're playing a melee champion, harass any time the person you're laning against is decently close. Again, never chase. Just go back to getting CS.